# C program to return perimeter and area of a rectangle

Tags: c

I want to write a c program to print the area and perimeter of a rectangle but i am getting a segmentation fault error.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int rectanglePerimeter(int h, int w)
{
    
    int p =(2*h)+(2*w);
    return p;
}

int rectangleArea(int h, int w)
{
    int a = h * w;
        return a;   
}

int main()
{
    int h, w, perimeter, area;
    printf("Tell me the height and width of the rectangle\n");

    scanf("%i", h);
    scanf("%i", w);
    
    perimeter = rectanglePerimeter(h, w);

    area = rectangleArea(h, w);

    printf("Perimeter of the rectangle = %i inches", perimeter);

    printf("Area of the rectangle = %i square inches", area);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain to me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: `scanf("%i", h);` => `scanf("%i", &h);`... even better `if (scanf("%i", &h) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: TheHawk3r, Save time, enable all compiler warnings to quickly catch problems with code like `scanf("%i", h);`.

Comment: So i need to acces the memory address.
Thank you!

Comment: I am writting in vim and using an online compiler.
Can you suggest any eviroment for linux to learn c into ?

Comment: Install `gcc` (but chances it is already installed) and you can keep using `vim` if you want

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with C programing language some functions require to work with memory address, that is the case with `scanf` function. Scanf function takes two arguments, the first is the type of data you are expecting, a int, a float, a char, etc; and second argument is where you will save this input, and this place is not a referece of the variable you are going to save but the memory address of the variable. This way `scanf` shall save the value read in the variable you are storing it.

```c
scanf("%i", &h);
scanf("%i", &w);
```